# I can't get an answer out of my C++ program

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using an online compiler (running windows 8 and can't get any others to work). My code runs and compiles and completes, but it doesn't work. It is supposed ask a user for the wind speed and temperature, put them in a formula to calculate wind chill, round them (using a 'homemade' round function), and output the answer. But it gives me nothing.

Thank you for your help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int input (int wspeed, int tempature);
int calculate (int tempature, int wspeed, int windChill);
int trunkate (int windChill, double wchill);
int output (int tempature, int wspeed, int windChill);
int advisoryWarning (int windChill);


int main() 
{
int wspeed=0, tempature=0, windChill=0;
double wchill=0;
int input (int& wspeed, int& tempature);
int calculate (int& tempature, int& wspeed, int& windChill);
int trunkate (int& windChill, double& wchill);
int output (int& tempature, int& wspeed, int& windChill);
int advisoryWarning (int& windChill);
return 0;
}

int input (int& wspeed, int& tempature)
{
cout<<"This is the input function\nPlease input the tempature outside in fahrenheit."<<endl;
cin>>tempature;
cout<<"Please input wind speed in miles per hour."<<endl;
cin>>wspeed;

if(tempature<-40||tempature>40)
{
    cout<<"Please input a valid tempature between -40 and 40"<<endl;
    cin>>tempature;
}

if(wspeed<0||wspeed>60)
{
    cout<<"Please input a valid wind speed between 0 and 60 mph"<<endl;
    cin>>wspeed;
}
return 0;
}

int calculate (int& tempature, int& wspeed, double& wchill)
{
cout<<"\nThis is calculating\n";
wchill=35.74+0.6215*(tempature)-35.75*(pow(wspeed, 0.16))+0.4275*tempature*pow(wspeed, 0.16);
return wchill;
}

int trunkate (int& windChill, int& wchill)
{
//This is the round function
cout<<"\nThis is the trunkator function\nThis is the exact answer: " << wchill<<endl;
if(wchill<0)
    wchill=wchill-0.5;
else
    wchill=wchill+0.5;
cout<<"this is windchill plus or minus a half: "<<wchill<<endl;
windChill=wchill;
cout<<"this is the final answer: "<<windChill<<endl;
return windChill;
}

int output (int& tempature, int& wspeed, int& windChill)
{
cout<<"\nthis is the output function\n";
cout<<"Tempature entered: "<<tempature<<endl<<"Wind Speed entered: "<<wspeed<<endl<<"Wind Chill: "<<windChill<<endl<<endl;
cout<<"Calling the advisory output function...";
return 0;
}

int advisory (int& windChill)

{
if(windChill<-50)
    cout<<"Life threatening: Fostbite can occur within 5 minutes.";
else if (windChill<-30)
    cout<<"Danger: Frostbite can occur within 10 minutes.";
else if (windChill<-15)
    cout<<"Warning: Frostbite can occur within 30 minutes.";
else if (windChill<20)
    cout<<"Advisory: Frostbite can occur with extended exposure.";
else if (windChill<40)
    cout<<"Notice: Wear cold weather clothing as needed for comfort.";
else
    cout<<"No significant cold weather risk.";
return 0;
}
```

Edit: Ok, so i thought it was something stupid, I'm sorry I am taking a coding class for the first time and having a bit of trouble. So take out the int& and replaced them with just int, but now I get only input to run.

I changed the code a bit.

Comment: Please recheck your coursework/tutorial/book. Your main function contains a bunch of function _declarations_. You're not calling any function.

Comment: You don't call functions this way: `int input (int& wspeed, int& tempature);`

Comment: why are you passing all those poor `int`s by reference?

Comment: If you want an example, look how you're calling the `pow` function in your code:  `pow(wspeed, 0.16)`  Does that look anything like the way you're calling your own functions?  Do you see `pow(double wspeed, double 0.16)`?

Comment: Especially non-const reference and then not modifying them, What happens when I want to pass a temporary?

Comment: Your main function makes completely no sense. Also, replace all `int&` and `double&` with `int` and `double`, because you don't need references here.

Comment: I miss the "doesn't demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem" closure reason so darn much…

Comment: Mat and PaulMcKenzie: Thank you! So very helpful! I don't mind looking things up, but I don't always know what I am supposed to be looking up

Comment: Look up on the internet "c++ function call versus function declaration".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main() 
{
    int wspeed=0, tempature=0, windChill=0;
    double wchill=0;
    input (int& wspeed, int& tempature);
    calculate (int& tempature, int& wspeed, int& windChill);
    trunkate (int& windChill, double& wchill);
    output (int& tempature, int& wspeed, int& windChill);
    advisoryWarning (int& windChill);
    return 0;
}
```

I fixed your main function for you. When you call other functions, you do NOT call the type of the function. When you make a function called

```
int function(){}
```

the int is only the return type. When you call another function, you only need to add the name of the function. In your int main, you only need to call using function();

Hope this helps. I'm not very good at explaining.